# Time frames for probable responses in addressed commentary to another participant re any Q & A

Tags: discussion, support

I'm wasting a certain amount of time checking for possible responses to comments I'd specifically addressed to other participants about their own commentary, questions, or answers.  During what time frame after their remarks is it reasonable to expect a response?  (I'm thinking that a response within any given time might be in some inverse proportion to their overall "reputation", as highly-reputed participants would tend to spend enough time on their commentary &/or Q&A to have relatively little time left for such individualized responses.)

Comment: No one owes anyone any response. Some people visit multiple times a day, some a few times a week, some only every couple of months or years. Not getting timely (or any) response to comments is normal.

Comment: So, why not make that an answer? (I'd probably have accepted it.)  Are you uncertain about it?  (I'm not zeroing in to be annoying:  It's just that the ranges of education and reputation on the site are "astronomically" large, so some might be worth waiting for.)

Comment: Everyone owes everyone else everything.  We're a species.  (Yes, the particulate matter in us includes space.  So what?  All matter does.)  The downvote and general attitude of the closure strike me as physically unrealistic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [curiousdanii's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343185/time-frames-for-probable-responses-in-addressed-commentary-to-another-participan/343200#comment1149408_343185) is the main answer.  But there are some tricks you might miss - I wasn't aware of them for a long time.

If you are requesting clarifying edits to questions, you might find the "favourites" feature useful.  You can mark the questions as favourites, and you can sort the favourites list in your profile by "activity".  Then you don't need to check for edits on each individual question.

With regard to comments, *hopefully* the user will know to [ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) you.  Some new users don't; that's the biggest problem I can think of here.

Edits to answers will also bump a question to the top of your favourites list (correct me if I'm wrong).  I don't think there is a convenient way to watch a specific answer; you just have to watch the whole question.

Or maybe you just mean "how often should I open StackExchange so I can check my inbox" (and favourites).  In that case, you could rely on the delayed [email notifications](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/10/08/improved-global-email-notifications/).  Or you might want to use the SE mobile app, to receive notifications.  (The app is no longer developed, but some people still say they find it useful for this).

Comment: "*If you are requesting clarifying edits to questions, you might find the "favourites" feature useful.*" I have a problem with that because I *tried* to use it for this. But I also wanted to use favourites for...well, favourites. As well as watching for a different things. It quickly becomes very hard to sort out why you've added a given question to favourites. If there were *categories*, then it'd be fine but as of now, to me it's unfeasible to favourite stuff just to watch for later.

Comment: The clarifications on pinging (-I'd known of the process, but it's unexpectedly complicated, and the development of some of its aspects on the AI side are vaguely impressive) are useful enough that I've bookmarked them.

Answer (score 5):

First, I think what you do is novel, to check manually for responses without depending on reply notifications. It means you care, and for that I personally appreciate you for that.

However, people are busy. They might read the comments, but they're either too busy to give proper reply, or don't have any such reply to begin with. We can't really know.

Bottom line: better not waste time on trying to figure this out, or give time frames. I got annoyed in the past here on Meta when comments I posted (usually on staff answers looking for updates) were ignored, but at some point I realized it's pointless to get annoyed, or to expect any reply.

Comment: I can imagine they're busy (the web being worldwide), so I'm figuring most of the respondents most favored with comments set their own approximate guidelines for reply time-frames, and modify those time frames occasionally.  I had imagined that the organization (PSE) had more paid staffers than I now think it does, so I'd imagined that it resembled a corporation more than a cooperative, and have now revised that estimate.